# What is Windows registry key for password history?

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-registry

Been searching all night for this... does anyone know the registry key for Windows XP/2003 to enforce password history? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/500.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: What do you mean by "password history" exactly?

Comment: Determines the number of unique new passwords that have to be associated with a user account before an old password can be reused. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/500.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: There is no "password history" registry key. If there was, it would be a major security hole. @Fran: That's password **policy**, not password **history**.

Comment: How would it be a major security hole? Every other password policy option is linked to a registry key.

Comment: It is a password policy to enforce password history. Ah, lets just chalk it up to semantics. :-) Anyone know?

Comment: Suggestion: dump the entire registry to e.g. text or xml, change the "password policy", dump the registry again, then compare the two dumps with e.g. the linux diff tool (I haven't used windows in years so I don't know how easy it is to get registry dumps.)

Comment: If you're looking for current or old passwords, they're not stored in the registry. The only things that would be found in the registry are restrictions for setting a ne password.

Answer (score 3):

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters
```

Value to check: [RefusePasswordChange](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781359%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [MaximumPasswordAge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775452%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[*Source: MS Technet Librairy*]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Windows XP/2003, but on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 it's apparently

```
Key:         HKLM\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account
Value:       F
Byte offset: 0x10   (0x3A corresponds to 0, 0x3B corresponds to 1)
```

It's in binary, maintained by LSASS, so I don't recommend you try to change it through undocumented means.